# Plymouth Splash screen doesn't work

Tags: linux, debian, grub2, boot-loader, plymouth

Info

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64
- Kernel: 6.1.0-10-amd64
- Desktop Environment: Plasma 5.27.5 (KDE)
- Hardware: 82HU IdeaPad Flex 5 14ALC05
  I am trying to use plymouth to display splash screen while booting. But after trying many times, I couldn't find a way to get it to work.

I followed the instructions from the link below and other websites.

https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth

Here is the grub's config file.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=3 splash  rd.udev.log-priority=3 vt.global_cursor_default=0 amdgpu.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="magenta/black"
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/ROG/theme.txt"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"

GRUB_BACKGROUND=""
```

Comment: I take it you've installed plymouth plymouth-themes etc, i.e. followed that whole guide

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes, I did.